# SQL Query for many-many relationship to display data in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I have come over some problem and couldn't really find a specific solution for my issue.
I have a database table named 'Champions'. It contains champions (with their names and their type). I have a table named 'User' that contains user data (name, password, email etc.). And I have a table called 'Owns'. It holds data of which user bought which champion. To do this, 'Owns' holds the foreignkeys UID and CID.

Now on my website I want to display all champions and their images. Unlocked champion images will be shown colored. Locked will be shown in black and white.

I will insert data into 'Owns' as soon as a user buys a champion. That means if I bought 3 champions of 10 available champions, how do I query the tables to show all 7 locked champions as "black and white" and all 3 unlocked champions in color?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LEFT JOIN should work in this case. If the OWNS.id is null then show in black & white, else show in color.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CHAMPIONS
LEFT JOIN OWNS ON CHAMPIONS.id = OWNS.cid AND OWNS.uid = 1;
```

Comment: No problem @TheProgressViewer, glad I could help